# Create mail with text in body

Tags: vba, excel-2013

The first part of the code will not create the email ever since I added the strBody line and all.

I got the code from Ron de Bruin's site and added some things to it to adjust it for my needs.

```
  Sub Send_Row()
    'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
    'Working in Excel 2000-2013
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim Ash As Worksheet
        Dim StrBody As String

        Set Ash = ActiveSheet
        On Error GoTo cleanup
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        StrBody = "Hello " & cel.Offset(, -1) & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                  "We regret to inform you that there was an issue with the January interface file and your elections were not" & "<br>" & _
                  "processed correctly.  In order to rectify this situation, we will issue new logs " & "<br>" & _
                  "you will not experience a big hit to time:" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                  "Please Check Proposed Adjustment Schedule below" & "<br>" & _
                  "Please contact ." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                  "Again, our sincere apologies for the mishaps with the interface file and any inconvenience this may have caused you." & "<br><br><br>"

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        For Each cell In Ash.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" _
               And LCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "yes" Then

                'Change the filter range and filter Field if needed
                'It will filter on Column B now (mail addresses)
                Ash.Range("A1:J200").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value

                With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End With

                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .To = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    .Subject = "Benefits Deductions"
                    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
                    .Display  'Or use .Send
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0

                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Ash.AutoFilterMode = False
            End If
        Next cell

    cleanup:
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

On the first line of the `StrBody = ...`, you use a variable named `cel`, which seems to be undefined, this is probably what is throwing your program off.

Comment: @William _Cell_ is declared, _Cel_ is not declared. Even if `Cel` _was_ declared, it hasn't been `Set` to a range when you try to include it in `StrBody`. If `Cel` is supposed to be `Cell`, try moving `StrBody =` into your `For Each Cell` loop.

Comment: @ARich I saw that while running the code step by step... Im still a rookie here sorry for the silly questions... Its working now, but just had a question regarding the info its pasting.

Comment: `For Each cell In Ash.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" _
           And LCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "yes" Then

            Ash.Range("C1:H200").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria2:=cell.Value` When I have this it only pastes the row where the headers are and not the information below for each person Im sending an email to... If I change the `Ash.Range("C1:H200")` Back to `Ash.Range("A1:H200")` it will give the the row with the data and the headers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the second question. The only difference between `.Range("C1:H200")` and `.Range("A1:H200")` is that the latter will get the first 200 rows of columns `A-H` whereas the former will get the first 200 rows of columns `C-H`